# Vertical scrollbar for an angular widget is not working in IE11

Tags: css, angular, widget

I have an angular widget which displays the user dropdown list. I have added the property "overflow-y: scroll;" and it is working fine in all the other browsers except IE11. When i click on the scroll bar, the dropdown is getting closed. I cannot remove this property or change it to hidden as i need a scroll bar for this dropdown. Is there any other alternative to fix this?

Comment: try -ms-overflow-style: auto

Comment: that did not work for me :(

Comment: Are you using flexbox on the (parent) element?

Comment: No. I am not using.